# insert into a table and return a value with procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I want to create a procedure that inserts into a table and returns it's primary key.
The primary key of table is uniqueidentyfire and it's guid is true

This is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pr_Tbl_Erae_Insert]
    @sfk_Dars varchar(20),
    @sfk_Ostad varchar(20),
    @byfk_Gerayesh tinyint,
    @ifk_term int,
    @guidErae_ID uniqueidentifier,
    @byGroup_Number tinyint,

AS
-- INSERT a new row in the table.
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_Erae]
(
    [fk_Dars],
    [fk_Ostad],
    [fk_Gerayesh],
    [fk_term],
    [Erae_ID],
    [Group_Number]
)
VALUES
(
    @sfk_Dars,
    @sfk_Ostad,
    @byfk_Gerayesh,
    @ifk_term,
    ISNULL(@guidErae_ID, (newid())),
    @byGroup_Number
)
```

I need to return `Erae_Id` when it inserted into table how can I do that?

Can I use from output variables? How?

Comment: What database server are you using? If it's SQL Server, you can look at SCOPE_IDENTITY() for example.

Comment: @dash `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` only handles `IDENTITY`, and a `NEWID()` isn't an `IDENTITY`

Comment: Good point. I would probably have made it an identity column though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) available, depending on your version; however, in this case it is probably easier (since you only have one row) to handle this separately:

```
IF @guidErae_ID IS NULL SET @guidErae_ID = NEWID()
```

then use `@guidErae_ID` "as is" in the `INSERT` (no `ISNULL`), and then either end with:

```
SELECT @guidErae_ID
```

and use `var result = (Guid)command.ExecuteScalar()`, or mark `@guidErae_ID` as `OUTPUT` in the parameter definition, and query it after calling `command.ExecuteNonQuery()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to return the value in the @guidErae_ID parameter that you've included, then you need to mark the parameter for output, and then set it in the proc:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pr_Tbl_Erae_Insert]
    @sfk_Dars varchar(20),
    @sfk_Ostad varchar(20),
    @byfk_Gerayesh tinyint,
    @ifk_term int,
    @guidErae_ID uniqueidentifier output,
    @byGroup_Number tinyint,

AS

If @guidErae_ID is null set @guidErae_ID = newid()

-- INSERT a new row in the table.
INSERT [dbo].[Tbl_Erae]
(
    [fk_Dars],
    [fk_Ostad],
    [fk_Gerayesh],
    [fk_term],
    [Erae_ID],
    [Group_Number]
)
VALUES
(
    @sfk_Dars,
    @sfk_Ostad,
    @byfk_Gerayesh,
    @ifk_term,
    @guidErae_ID,
    @byGroup_Number
)
```

Comment: it has following error:Procedure or function 'Test_Insert' expects parameter '@guidErae_ID, which was not supplied.

Comment: You must have missed the parameter from your call to the proc - the call needs to match the parameters, and there needs to be a parameter to receive the value returned from the proc.

Comment: i put the @a empty and b='jo'

Answer (score 0):

at the end of your stored procedure just add one more line like this

```
return select Erae_Id WHERE [fk_Dars] = @sfk_Dars
    AND
    [fk_Ostad] = @sfk_Ostad
    AND
    [fk_Gerayesh] = @byfk_Gerayesh
    AND
    [fk_term] = @ifk_term
    AND
    [Group_Number] = @byGroup_Number
```